# My Index page is not seeing the javascript library I loaded in my shared layout page

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm trying to use a javascript library in one of my .Net Core 3.1 Razor pages.

So I added these to my `_Layout.cshtml` page:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/gameRec/gr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then in my Index.cshtml, I am trying to use `gr` like this:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<head runat="server">
    <script>
        gr.init({
            selector: 'textarea#record',
            height: 500,
            width: 25,
            view_style: 'body { font-size:14px }'
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">GAME PORTAL</h1>
    <p>GAME</p>
    <div id="gameContainer">
        <textarea id="record" asp-for="game" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it keeps telling me this:

> (index):34 Uncaught ReferenceError: gr is not defined

Now I checked, and I know the library is in the correct place.

So Im not sure why my Index page can't find it.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not related to ASP....

Comment: @DavidEdel Oh sorry, I apologize. I am using razor pages in my .net core mvc project.  I will see if I can delete the asp references.  thanks!

Comment: @DavidEdel Ok I removed everything but `razor`, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag <head should be in Layout

All you script files should be in layout at the bottom of the body

```
<body>
......
 <script src="~/js/gameRec/gr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

immediately after this add

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and move your custom script in the botom of index file

```
@section Scripts {

    <script>

...... your custom script

    </script>

}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so my `<script> gr.init({ ... }) </script>` goes at the very bottom of my index file?

Comment: yes,  it's usually wrapped by $(document).ready(function () {....your code ... });